# Prolog: Can't increase value of variable inside complex term

Tags: syntax, prolog

So I'm working on a prolog problem where a state is defined in a complex term, When I try to increase the value of x inside this complex term nothing happens for example

```
CurrentState(left, x, y).



test = CurrentState(left, x,y),
newX = x + 1,
write(newX).
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Short answer: Prolog does not allow the direct mutation of compound terms. Good news: mutation is almost always unnecessary.

Comment: Improve the syntax of the terms you specify: functors (atom and compound names) start with a lowercase, logical variables start with a uppercase character. As a result, `CurrentState(left,x,y)` is not a syntactically valid term. Also, the goal `newX = x + 1` *always fails*. Fix this so we can help you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdabv9EkYrY is a nice intro to representing states in Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

Facts and predicates need to start with a lowercase letter.

Variables need to start with an uppercase letter.

`=` is not assignment, and Prolog predicates aren't function calls, and you never use `test` anyway.

Even then, what do you want `x + 1` to do when you haven't given any value for x? It makes no more sense than `left + 1` written like that.

It would all be more like:

```
currentState(left, 5, 2).   % fact

test(NewX) :-
    currentState(Direction, X, Y),   % search for the fact, fill the variables.
    NewX is X + 1,                   % new variable for new value.
    write(NewX).
```

Then

```
?- test(NewX).
6
NewX = 6
```

After that you still don't want to be storing the state as a fact in the Prolog database and removing/asserting it.